# Xcode CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: xcode

I received the following warning message in Xcode, but I am unsure how to resolve it.
I have Widget & Intents extension in my app.

The message:
The CFBundleShortVersionString of an app extension ('1.0') must match that of its containing parent app ('2.0.1').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means that you have one or more extensions in your project. E.g., "Notification Service Extension" or a Watch extension.

All of them have their own targets. The targets have "Version" and "Build" fields in the "General" tab, as well as your main app target.

Those values should all match between the main target and the extension targets.